# How to read .odt files and extract text in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I have been trying to read the odt files and extract text from it in Node js.
I cannot find certain dependency to do the same efficiently.

Comment: have a look at this 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract